# restrict crontab from executing on 0th minute for a range of minutes

Tags: cron

I have a cronjob setup to run every 14 minutes using below format.

```
*/14 * * * * command
```

Now this cron runs every 0,14,28,42,56 minutes. I dont want it to run on 0th minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the count start at 14 with `14-59/14` or, as suggested by @steeldriver in a comment, use an explicit list: `14,28,42,56`.